# How to upload pdf file from wordpress page and file must get saved in wp-content upload directory folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

How to upload pdf file from wordpress page?

```html
<form action="" method="POST"> 
 <input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
 <?php

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file-upload', $post->ID);
?>
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Iam doing this first time so please help.

Comment: Do you want to upload pdf file in front end?

Comment: sorry i did not explain properly what I want is: there will be a form where user with choose the file and when they click submit button, this pdf file will be saved in wordpress wamp/wp-content/upload folder.

Comment: On front end right?

Comment: haan yes On front end

Comment: Okey let me try

Comment: Please check my below answer and let me know its working for you

Comment: sorry wait let me check.

Comment: this code is Not working

Comment: Its working for me its uploaded pdf in uploads folder.where you put this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this :



    <?php
        function upload_user_file( $file = array() ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );
              $file_return = wp_handle_upload( $file, array('test_form' => false ) );
              if( isset( $file_return['error'] ) || isset( $file_return['upload_error_handler'] ) ) {
                  return false;
              } else {
                  $filename = $file_return['file'];
                  $attachment = array(
                      'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                      'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                      'post_content' => '',
                      'post_status' => 'inherit',
                      'guid' => $file_return['url']
                  );
                  $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_return['url'] );
                  require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                  $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
                  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
                  if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
                    return $attachment_id;
                  }
              }
              return false;
        }
        ?>
    <?php
    if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) {
      foreach( $_FILES as $file ) {
        if( is_array( $file ) ) {
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file );
        }
      }
    }
    ?>

 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: this above code is working if I write just this above code but i have some more content on my admin page so if I add my content its giving errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in templates or any page.I tested and confirmed its working for me.

```
 <?php

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file-upload', $post->ID);        
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```